# Running sstableutil after installing and running cassandra using docker

Tags: docker, cassandra

I want to run some of the programs in SSTable Tools however the doc says:
*Cassandra must be stopped before these tools are executed, or unexpected results will occur. Note: the scripts do not verify that Cassandra is stopped.*

I installed and started cassandra using docker. So how do I run something like sstableutil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, but you need to make sure that you have data on the host system, or in the Docker volume (it's good idea anyway):

- stop container
- execute `docker run -it ...volume_config... --rm cassandra sstable_command`
- start container

P.S. But it really depends on the command - I remember that some commands were documented as required stop, but not really required